# Was Dr. Zakir Naik wrong while explaining the meaning of alazina kafaroo (الَّذِينَ كَفَرُوا)?

Tags: non-muslim, quran-translation, surat-al-baqarah

Assalamu alaikum. I came up with a doubt when reading the answer from [this website](https://islamtheultimatejourney.wordpress.com/questions-faq-on-islam-by-zakir-naik/most-common-questions-asked-by-non-muslims-who-have-some-knowledge-of-islam/). It was an answer given by Dr. Zakir Naik.

> Question: If Allah has sealed the hearts of the Kuffar i.e. non-Muslims, then why are they to be blamed for not accepting Islam?
>
> Answer:
>   1.    Allah has sealed the hearts of those who are continuously bent on rejecting the truth
>
> Allah (swt) mentions in Surah Al Baqarah chapter 2 verses 6 and 7
>
> **“As to those who reject Faith, it is the same to them Whether thou warn them or do not warn them; they will not believe.**
>
> **Allah hath set a seal on their hearts and on their hearing, and on their eyes is a veil; great is the penalty they (incur).”
>   [Al-Qur’an 2:6-7]**
>
> These verses do not refer to common Kuffar who reject faith. The Arabic words used are al-lazina kafaroo, those who are bent on rejecting the truth. It will not make any difference to such people whether you warn them or not, they will not believe. Allah has set a seal on their hearts and on their hearing and on their eyes is a veil. It is not because Allah has set a seal on their hearts that these kuffar do not understand and believe, but it is the vice-versa. It is because these kuffar are bent on rejecting the truth and whether you warn them or not they will not believe, that Allah has set a seal on their hearts. Therefore Allah is not to blame, but these kuffaar who are bent on rejecting the faith are responsible.

In this explanation he says that it doesn't refers to common kaafir but alazina kafaroo, those who are bent on rejecting the truth.

But when I referred in [this website.](http://corpus.quran.com/wordbyword.jsp?chapter=2&verse=6) the translation for alazina kafaroo (الَّذِينَ كَفَرُوا) was those who disbelieved. well as we know that kaafir refers to the person who rejected truth or in other words who covered or hided or rejected truth. I think translation refers to common or all of kaafir and not 
those who are bent on rejecting the truth.

Well my question is,

1. Was my reference wrong? Then please explain with proof.

Comment: I think he means to say that "those who are disbelieving" denotes an actively disbelieving person while disbeliever is a general term for people who have disbelieved (maybe they just don't care or pay attention to the message). The active disbelievers are what Allah is condemning. Kind of like the difference between "thieves" and "those who are stealing".

Comment: Well according to a definition of the word kafir from Quora (https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-exact-meaning-of-word-Kafir-in-Quran) its given that, "Kafir, as evidenced from the Quran, is a 'state' that one 'enters' into once the truth has been clearly manifested to them, made absolutely clear and there is no reason left to deny it." So according to this definition, your claim that "(maybe they just don't care or pay attention to the message)" is wrong. And is there any historival evidence or reference to prove your claim that it refers to a particular kafirs? @TheZ

Comment: I don't see your point. People disbelieve in the face of clear proofs for many reasons one of which is "not caring enough to pay attention". Secodly, I based my comment on a simple grammatical fact that one phrase has an active verb (those who disbelieve) in it while the other (disbeliever) only implies a quality which may or may not be currently active.

Comment: It is advisable to re-edit your question to make it clear what you are asking about. The title suggests you are asking our opinion about a specific scholar, which is presumably quoted in an unattributed blog without reference, which you yourself have misquoted or partially quoted. In the body, you are asking our opinion about what Allah's motives, which we cannot tell without speculating. Finally, Quora is not an Islamic reference that is accepted as credible.

Comment: Allazina: those who, kafaroo: Denied, Rejected, means after knowing the truth, those who denied it. Those will not come in it who don't know the truth

Comment: @III-AK-III Edited as requested. And that question and answer was actually seen on Zakir Naik's website www.irf.net once. But when it was banned.. the contents on that website were actually copy/pasted in many websites like the one which I linked. Since the reason i read that once on his website. I am sure that that was his answer and it's even posted in that website that that is his answer. Well I am not asking your opinion. I asked here so that people like you could find me the answer for my question from the Quran. Because i dont have much knowledge of what's given in Quran.

Comment: @MohmedShahid, your question is still closed. You will need to request re-opening as closed questions cannot be answered.